# NoSQL traversing using referenced conditions

Tags: architecture, nosql

I'm looking into NoSQL technologies and I have explored a bit of MongoDB, Riak and Neo4j.

I'm asking if any of them can really handle the problem of traversing or retrieving data based on conditions on a related entity.

Assume I have got a tags table[id,title,created], a posts table[id,title,body], and a posts_tags table[post_id,tag_id],

I want to return the posts which contains a tag that was created earlier than Aug 5, 2012. 
In an SQL world it would be easy, but is this problem can be solved using NoSQL technologies ?

I'm not limited to the NoSQL options mentioned above, if anyone have got recommendation on other engines its most welcomed.

I'm just trying to know if this problem can be solved in the world of NoSQL and which engines support that the solution for that kind of problem.

Question 2: Are those entities correctly modelled in the NoSQL approach?

Question 3: Is it worth it in terms of **performance** to go for one of the NoSQL options or would it still be slow? (suppose I have got 2 million posts and a few thousand tags)

Answer (score 0):

I think all three of those NoSQL technologies would perform better in a denormalized model where the tags are all directly contained in the post record. The trouble is that you want to keep track of the time the tags are created, which is a bit more annoying than just the tags, but you could still do it. You could have a tags collection as you describe, and then you'd copy over the created time when you add a tag to a post. It gets a bit more complex if you want to be able to remove tags from the system.

In mongodb (the one I have the most experience), you could do something like this:

posts collection example:

```
{
  _id: ...,
  title: "test title",
  body: "body",
  tags: [
    {
      title: "test tag",
      created: ISODate("2012-08-05T02:45:40.575Z")
    },
    { 
      title: "test tag2",
      created: ISODate("2012-08-05T02:47:37.124Z")
    }
  ] 
}
```

Then your query would be something like:

```
db.posts.find({"tags.created":{$gt:new Date("2012/08/05")}});
```

And having an index on `tags.created` would speed that up.

TL;DR: Trying to have join tables in most of the NoSQL technologies really isn't performant.

Updating to add a bit from a neo4j perspective:

It occurred to me that you could relate tags and posts relatively easily in neo4j (without a join table, since relationships are effectively permanent joins). You'd search for less than 2012/08/05, and then find the posts related to those tags. No denormalization needed. Theoretically this is performant, although I'm not a neo4j expert yet. It would look something like this in Cypher:

```
START post=node(*) 
MATCH post<-[:tagged]-tag 
WHERE tag.created < "2012-08-05" 
RETURN post, tag;
```

You can probably make this query faster by indexing `created` and making START match the index, instead of using WHERE. In this example, I made `created` an ISO date string, and the relationship type was `tagged`.

Comment: Thanks alot for your explanation, however what if I wanted to list distinct tags? for auto-completion for instance.

Excuse my poor example of the problem definition, but suppose also that I have got alot of meta-data about the tags not just the creation date. Would this solution still be better ?

Comment: For distinct tags you could still use your tags collection. As for your other metadata, it really depends. If it's one-time configuration metadata that you want to set up about a tag, that's one thing (and it would be easy to denormalize it), but if you want to be able to update the metadata and would need to propagate changes to all of your denormalized posts, you're going to suffer whenever you need to do that.

Comment: @omar.php You can use [distinct()](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Distinct) if you just want the tag titles.

Answer (score 0):

With Couchbase, you can store the tags inline, just like in Wes's answer, but then use create a view index which allows easy query for all tags with prefix "app" eg this can return Apple and application and apply.

This article describes what went into building an autocomplete tag search on Couch: http://blog.couchbase.com/typeahead-search-couchdb

It's a little old but the general pattern still applies.

Answer (score 0):

Since, as you mention, it would be easy to solve your problems using SQL, maybe you should consider a NewSQL database, see [NoSQL, NewSQL and Beyond](http://www.infoq.com/news/2011/04/newsql/)